# How to fix 'Cannot read property click' error in JS

Tags: javascript

I'm try to make a little bot for delete my instagram pictures and write a code for this. Actually there is no delete picture option for desktop version of instagram. But when you change User Agent to Mobile Phone, you can.

I used Google Dev Console for trying the code. If you write the code one by one it is OK. But when I make it a function, get this error. `Cannot read property 'click'`

```
var username = prompt("Please enter your instagram account", "myinstagramacc");

window.location.replace("https://instagram.com/"+username);


function deletePics(){


    setTimeout(() =>  document.getElementsByClassName("_9AhH0")[0].click(), 1000);
    setTimeout(() =>  document.getElementsByTagName("button")[5].click()  , 1000);
    setTimeout(() =>  document.getElementsByTagName("button")[7].click()  , 1000);
    setTimeout(() =>  document.getElementsByTagName("button")[7].click()  , 1000);

}

for(i=0;i<17;i++)
  setTimeout(deletePics(),1000);
```

**Expected**

Browser will take my username then go my home screen and delete picture with click the picture, click three dots icon then select Delete then select Delete.

**Actual Result** 
After taking username, going my home screen and clicking first picture I saw this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined
    at setTimeout (<anonymous>:3:65)
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined
    at setTimeout (<anonymous>:4:65)
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined
    at setTimeout (<anonymous>:5:65)
```

Comment: Should be `setTimeout(deletePics, 1000)` but because loading the instagram page will completely destroy the previous page contents it cannot possibly work anyway.

Comment: one of the `document.getElementsByClassName` return `undefined` post your html so we could examin

Comment: `_9AhH0` may different for you. right click the picture and select Inspect. It will show your class name.

Answer (score 0):

The function call was wrong

```js
var username = prompt("Please enter your instagram account", "myinstagramacc");
//window.location.replace("https://instagram.com/"+username);
function deletePics() {
  setTimeout(() => document.getElementsByClassName("_9AhH0")[0].click(), 1000);
  setTimeout(() => document.getElementsByTagName("button")[5].click(), 1000);
  setTimeout(() => document.getElementsByTagName("button")[7].click(), 1000);
  setTimeout(() => document.getElementsByTagName("button")[7].click(), 1000);
}
for (i = 0; i < 17; i++)
  setTimeout(deletePics, 1000);
```

```html
<div class="_9AhH0">aa</div>
<button>click</button><button>click</button><button>click</button><button>click</button><button>click</button><button>click</button><button>click</button><button>click</button>
```